# Get values from Service into Activity

Tags: java, android, service

I wrote below code using fusedapi to get lat and longi.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

/**
 * Created by DELL WORLD on 1/24/2017.
 */

public class LocationWithFusedApi extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    double lat, lon;
     final static String Mydata = "MyData";

  /*  public LocationWithFusedApi() {
        super("LocationWithFusedApi");
    }*/
/*
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d("LocationWithFusedAPI", "Called");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

   /* @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        System.out.println("Latest" + lat + ":" + lon);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("Mydata");
        intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
        intent.putExtra("lon",lon);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        sendlat();
        sendlon();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100); // Update location every second

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            lon = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            System.out.println("Last" + lat + ":" + lon);
            sendlat();
            sendlon();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    public double sendlat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public double sendlon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void removeupdate() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

Now trying to get lat and lon values in another activity to show to user via calling sendlat and sendlon but getting null. what mistake m I doing.
Here is code for activity where I m trying to get values.

```
  public class ShareLocation extends AppCompatActivity {
    GPSDataPicker gps;
    String clickable = "";
    Latlonreceiver latlonreceiver;
    double lat, lon;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        latlonreceiver = new Latlonreceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(LocationWithFusedApi.Mydata);
        registerReceiver(latlonreceiver, intentFilter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ShareLocation.this, LocationWithFusedApi.class);
        startService(intent);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       /* LocationWithFusedApi locationWithFusedApi = new LocationWithFusedApi();
        double latitude = locationWithFusedApi.sendlat();
        double longitude = locationWithFusedApi.sendlon();*/

        double latitude = lat;
        double longitude = lon;
        setContentView(R.layout.sharelocation);



                        clickable = "https://maps.google.com/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
}
}
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(latlonreceiver);
    }
  public class Latlonreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0.0);
            lon = intent.getDoubleExtra("lon", 0.0);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `BroadcastReceiver` in the second (receiving) activity, and put those two values as extras in your broadcasted Intent. Also, make sure to register/unregister `IntentFilters` in `onCreate()`, `onResume()` and `onPause()` and `onDestroy()`.

Comment: not working. still same issue. I am putting updated code.

Comment: is on `onReceive()` even firing / getting called?

Comment: no value received in receiver, neither it is being called.

Comment: if the broadcast isn't being sent - fix it....

Comment: it is done. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have helped resolve the issue. Feel free to write up an answer to your question and accept it, for future reference and/or readers facing a similar issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133980/discussion-between-panache-and-shark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using broadcast receiver. The basic mistake here is that the retrieval of the location is running on a different thread asynchronously. So by the time you call your sendXxx() methods the location has not been resolved yet. With asynchronous code you need the service to push you the result after the location has been resolved. The standard way in this case would be the broadcast receiver.